# Reliable locking between containers on the same box

Tags: python, containers

I have a project that runs a bunch of Docker containers on the same instance. Each container has to process some file system resource exclusively so I have to lock the resource. I am currently using the `filelock==3.0.12` module in Python 3.8 but it is not very reliable. I observed that if two containers require the lock at almost the same time it happens frequently that both containers can acquire the lock. Is there a better option than `filelock`?

Comment: Can you specify what your criteria for ``reliable`` is? ``filelock`` should work fine on any filesystem with full POSIX semantics (most importantly atomicity and immediate consistency – many distributed file systems do not provide this). If there is no filesystem or other service providing atomic, exclusive ownership there is no truly reliable locking possible.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `filelock` should work fine. What I am seeing is that if two containers try to acquire the same lock at almost the same time, both can acquire it which creates a race condition. I would say it is a bug in the `filelock` module. I am just looking for something that is reliable in this case. I am running it on an EC2 instance of CentOS.

Comment: I am not saying ``filelock`` should work fine – I am saying it should work fine on a filesystem providing "local" filesystem behaviour. ``filelock`` is bound to the guarantees by the kernel/filesystem managing the lock file. Since your container instances are unlikely to share the same kernel, whether or not ``filelock`` works depends on your filesystem setup. See for example the notes on [flock for NFS](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/flock.2.en.html#NFS_details).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue too. While clumsy and there might be a better approach, it seems like the lock only fails when the race is VERY close. As a result, it appears to be working to use a SECOND file lock on a second file and use a random fraction-of-a-second sleep time before obtaining the lock.

It basically amounts to this:

```
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        stack.enter_context(first_lock)
        time.sleep(random.random())
        stack.enter_context(second_lock)

        do_that_thing_im_trying_to_protect()
```

Of course, throwing in a sleep might be really bad for your usecase. For mine, we only do this once at start-up, so it can be excused. It's the only thing I can think of to deal with this issue, short of relying on a databased-based lock like Redlock (Redis).